# Issues Getting Receipt Verification Working With ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, asihttprequest, storekit

I am trying to verify a non-renewable subscription with Apple's sandbox server but keep getting back `verify response: { "status":21002 }` which means the request is malformed. Here is the relevant code I am using:

```
    NSString *receiptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:transactionReceipt
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *encodedString = [receiptString base64Encoding];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ 'receipt-data' : '%@' }", encodedString];

    NSURL *verificationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:verificationURL];
    [request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"verify response: %@", responseString);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"verify error: %@", [error description]);
    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Apparently the problem is the way I am sending the data to Apple through the ASIHTTPRequest library. Any insight on this appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use another code. Example,

[IAP_Validation](https://github.com/evands/iap_validation)